# Join Two table by condition with CriteriaBuilder

Tags: sql, jpa, join, criteria-api

I have a tables where i save different cars, in the price table i save the history of the prices to the car's dependend on the region where the seller is located.
It works all fine, but how can i get all car's for a seller with only the price history for that car?

Car Table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(unique = true)
private String numberPlate;
private String carName;
...

@Lob
@Column(columnDefinition="mediumblob")
private byte[] image;
private float lastPrise;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "car")
private List<ProductPrice> carPrices;
}
```

Price Table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "price")
@EntityListeners({ProductPrice.WritableEntityListener.class})
public class CarPrice {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(nullable = false)
private Date created;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String createdBy;

private float price;

@OneToOne
private Region region;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "car_id", nullable = false)
private Car car;

private Date priceDate;
private Date priceDateFrom;
private Date priceDateTo;
}
```

Region Table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "region")
public class Region {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private Long regionId;
private String regionName;
}
```

How can i get all car's for a region (by region id).

If I use the following sql statement i get a result I expected

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(pp.priceDate) AS datePrice, c.id, c.CarName, c.numberPlate, c.description, c.lastPrise, pp.price, g.name, pp.grocery_id
FROM car p, region g
JOIN price pp
WHERE
c.id=pp.product_id
AND pp.region_id=g.id
AND pp.region_id=570
ORDER BY c.name, pp.region_id, datePrice;
```

but how can i build this with CriteriaBuilder.

The next snippet shows my solution but I get not only the price history for the selected region_id, but also for all regions.

```
public List<Car> getCarAndLatestPrice(Long id) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Car> qry = cb.createQuery(Car.class);
    Root<Car> car = qry.from(Car.class);
    //Root<Region> region = qry.from(Region.class);
    Join<Car, ProductPrice> price = car.join("productPrices");

    qry.distinct(true);
    qry.select(car);
    qry.orderBy(cb.asc(car.get("name")));

    List<Predicate> conditions = new ArrayList<>();
    conditions.add(cb.equal(price.get("region"), id));

    TypedQuery<Car> typedQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(qry
            .select(car)
            .where(conditions.toArray(new Predicate[]{}))
            .distinct(true));

    List<Car> productList = typedQuery.getResultList();
    return productList;
}
```

Maybe someone have a similar problem and can provide my a solution.

Comment: so why not actually look at the SQL generated and it may show you where you have the problem ...

Comment: I done more tests and found in my sql statement above a failure there is in the from statement region g. if so i get also prices for all regions.

Comment: If i change my criteriabuilder function and add                                             qry.where(cb.equal(car.get("id"), price.get("car").get("id"))); the generated sql is the same to my statement without region, but the result in hibernat is the same

Comment: @ducky12 What is your expected SQL?